# Running a php script on a phonegap application

Tags: javascript, php, android, ajax, cordova

I am building an app that pulls data from a database. I am using ajax to run the php script which is located on my external server and attempting to return the data is json format.
Every time I attempt to run the function that calls the script I get an error stating that the URL can not be found.
I have added my server domain to the whitelist in my config file. I'm not sure what else to do and any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code.

index.html javascript to run the php script:

```
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#articlelist", function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://domain/App/script/getArticleList.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data:{catid: catid},
            success: function(data){
                alert("success");
                $("#article-list").empty();
                var li="";
                $.each(data, function(i,item){
                    li += '<li><a href="" data-class="artSelection" id="'+data[i].id+'">'+data[i].title+'</a></li>';
                });

                $("#article-list").append(li).promise();
                $("#article-list").listview('refresh');
            },
            error:function(x,e){
                if(x.status==0){
                    alert('You are offline!!\n Please Check Your Network.');
                }else if(x.status==404){
                    alert('Requested URL not found.');
                }else if(x.status==500){
                    alert('Internel Server Error.');
                }else if(e=='parsererror'){
                    alert('Error.\nParsing JSON Request failed.');
                }else if(e=='timeout'){
                    alert('Request Time out.');
                }else {
                    alert('Unknow Error.\n'+x.responseText);
                }
            }
        });
```

getArticleList.php:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['catid'])){
        $server = "localhost";
        $username = "username";
        $password = "password";
        $database = "database";

        $con = mysqli_connect ($server, $username, $password, $database) or die ('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
        mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");

        $list = array();
        switch($catid){
            case "catid=21":
                $qry = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT title, id FROM u9wkx_content WHERE ".$catid." AND publish_down >= NOW() ORDER BY `ordering` ASC");
                break;
            case "catid=90":
                $qry = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT title, id FROM u9wkx_content WHERE ".$catid." AND publish_down >= NOW() ORDER BY `title` ASC");
                break;
            case "catid=19":
                $qry = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT title, id FROM u9wkx_content WHERE ".$catid." AND publish_down >= NOW() ORDER BY `ordering` ASC");
                break;
            case "catid=107":
                $qry = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT title, id FROM u9wkx_content WHERE ".$catid." AND publish_down >= NOW() ORDER BY `ordering` ASC");
                break;
            case "catid=42":
                $qry = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT title, id FROM u9wkx_content WHERE ".$catid." AND publish_down >= NOW() ORDER BY `ordering` ASC");
                break;
            default:
                $qry = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT title, id FROM u9wkx_content WHERE ".$catid." AND publish_down >= NOW()");
        }

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qry)){
        $list[] = $row;
        }
    }


    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $list_data = json_encode($list);

    echo $list_data;
?>
```

Comment: Try accessing the URL from somewhere else, e.g. using the Postman plugin for Chrome, and post the results in your question. That would help in troubleshooting.

Comment: When accessing the URL through the browser it returns a 404 error. But when I go into my cpanel file manager the file is there.

Comment: You already tried to add www in front of your domain didn't you?

Comment: Cpanel file manager? Please tell the full path you see. I think you put the script in the wrong directory. Please also tell the document root of your webserver.

Comment: You should use a browser running on the same device as your app.

Comment: `added my server domain to the whitelist in my config file.`. Config file of what?

Comment: @Glenn **When accessing the URL through the browser it returns a 404 error** . If you ask me, this seems to be your problem - the script is inaccessible. Has nothing to do with Phonegap.